# Error using Firebase authentication RecaptchaVerifier in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

I am trying to implement 2FA using Angular 12 and Firebase. But I keep on getting an error at the very start of the process in ngAfterViewInit:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.windowRef = this.win.windowRef;
    this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
      'size': 'invisible',
      'callback': (response: any) => {
        console.log('callback ==>',response);
      }
    });
    this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier.render();      
  }
```

I am following [this example](https://dotnetdetail.net/how-to-add-two-factor-authentication-2fa-in-angular-7-using-firebase/) mainly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in my html. I had a `<div id="recaptcha-container"></div>` inside an if condition that was false. I moved it out of that if condition and it worked fine.

Comment: The example has 2 elements with id = recaptcha-container

Answer (score 0):

okay i fixed the problem i think, i'm using nextjs 14+ so the problem was that is didn't create a div or any html element whose id is

> **'recaptcha-container'**

one of the bug with the above one could be this and the next problem is you should put your auth initialization as a first argument of **RecaptchaVerifier**

check it out here

```html
this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(auth, 'recaptcha-container', {
      'size': 'invisible',
      'callback': (response: any) => {
        console.log('callback ==>',response);
   }
});
```